# Typescript runtime error: cannot read property of undefined (enum)

Tags: typescript, enums, undefined

I have the following interface and enum in a file *RESTConfig.ts*:

```
export const enum RESTMethod {
   POST = "POST",
   GET = "GET"
}

export interface RESTConfig {
   url: string;
   method: RESTMethod;
   data: any;
}
```

I want to import and use the enum in another class as such:

```
import { RESTConfig, RESTMethod } from './RESTConfig';

class Pipelines {
   ...
   private someMethod() {
      let rest: RESTConfig = {
         url: "",
         method: RESTMethod.POST,
         data: {}
      }
      ...

   }
   ...
}
```

Linting and transpiling works fine, but at runtime I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'POST' of undefined

on the line "method: RESTMethod.POST".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did find the answer?

Comment: make the enum not constant - remove 'const' term

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Typescript there are 2 kinds of enums:

- *Classic* `enum`:

During TS to JS transpilation they are converted to real objects, so they exist at runtime.

```
enum Response {
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1,
}

const yes = Response.Yes; // Works at runtime

const nameOfYes = Response[yes]; // Also works at runtime because a reverse mapping is also generated during transpilation
```

- `const enum` (the one you are using):

Const enums are removed during transpilation in JS so you can not use them at runtime. As per [TS doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) const enums exists to *avoid paying the cost of extra generated code and additional indirection when accessing enum values*.

```
const enum Response {
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1,
}

const yes = Response.Yes; // At runtime: ReferenceError: Response is not defined

const nameOfYes = Response[yes]; // During transpilation: TS2476: A const enum member can only be accessed using a string literal.
```

---

So just change your `const enum` to `enum` and your runtime error will be gone.

Comment: Also happens when you `export declare enum`.

Comment: @MichałTatarynowicz how do you workaround this if you need to `export` your enum but also need to use it at runtime?

Answer (score 142):

I just found out the hard way that this can also happen if you have circular imports.

Comment: This is what bit me

Comment: Seems that is not so hard to happen!

Comment: This should go upward further

Comment: I believe this is [TypeScript/issues/3200](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3200)

Answer (score 15):

And if you want to identify your circular dependencies, run
`npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./`

(Credit: Andrejs Abrickis's blog https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/locate-circular-dependencies-in-typescript-modules-2b1eb03dbf2e)

Comment: This fixed my error

Answer (score 6):

It works for me when put enum into an independent file

Comment: Probably you had a circular dependency

Answer (score 2):

If you have this issue while running tests make sure that the file with the `enum` is included in the `tsconfig.spec.json` file.

e.g. when the enum is in a `types.ts` file

```
{
  [...]
  "include": ["types.ts"]
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export enum RESTMethod {
   POST = "POST",
   GET = "GET"
}

import { RESTConfig, RESTMethod } from './RESTConfig';

class Pipelines {
   ...
   private someMethod() {
      let restMethodEnum = RESTMethod;
      let rest: RESTConfig = {
         url: "",
         method: restMethodEnum.POST,
         data: {}
      }
      ...

   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `--isolatedModules` in tsconfig.json or `transpileOnly` in ts-loader, you may be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16671). Basically, you cannot use these things in combination with `export const enum`.

In the words of a commenter there:

> `transpileOnly` means transpile every file one at a time.. when the compiler is looking at one file, it has no way to know if the reference it is looking at is a const enum or not, since the declaration is in another file that it does not have access to..
>
> so I do not think you can mix these two concepts, `const enum`s (require whole program information), and `transpileOnly` (one file at a time).