# Verify that a value is part of an enum

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, enums

I am on Angular **13.3.9**, using typescript **4.6.4.**
My goal is to know if a value refers to an enum.

Here my code,

```
export enum HttpFunctionalErrorCodes {
  ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND = 'ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND',
  USER_ALREADY_EXISTS = 'USER_ALREADY_EXISTS',
  BAD_CREDENTIALS = 'BAD_CREDENTIALS'
}
```

**My export enum is a part of a npm library that is already compiled...**

```
import { HttpFunctionalErrorCodes } from ...;

  computeError(error: any): void {
    console.log(error.code) // BAD_CREDENTIALS
    console.log(HttpFunctionalErrorCodes) // undefined
    if (!_.isNil(error.code) && error.code in HttpFunctionalErrorCodes) {
    // TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'BAD_CREDENTIALS' in undefined
      ...
    }
  }
```

In this code, I catch an error that I pass in the computeError function.
In this method, I'm trying to find out if the code is an HttpFunctionalErrorCodes, which is an enum.
But I get this error `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'BAD_CREDENTIALS' in undefined`

After some research, I finally found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53232849/10872189
which says that with a classic enum I shouldn't have any problem.

I also try this:

```
error.code in Object.values(HttpFunctionalErrorCodes)
```

And have this error : `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

But when I try on TSPlayground, it works !
[typescriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEgLnADgMTCAxnAlgexAQwBsBRAJ1J1IGEcATYAZygG8AoKKAQSqoHkBVAHIAVAPqDeY5AMEARKAF4oAcm58hYiVJmzlAGnZR+AZWIAlUZwAyZ4p1kBNUcQAaASWPDjilSfOWbO0dnd09jfUMAIXtRKltZYhE3a28lZWjZWPjE4WSrcNYAX1ZWdDwGOCgyiEQwOGAyClIfAApgckoALih8EABPAEpFAD4WQw4ykAYcQmAAOkIcAHM2jtI5svoB8arymfnFlfgkVAxsPCJGyhp6Bm2ODiwAMyhVpo26YCgAMm+odvemy+WBAsAQKDQmFwBBIaxujCGbAeD0m01mC2WLWUWEqAHdKABrJgAQmU9wexQ4xVKOBqdQaaxazF29G6qh4Mk0klE0iEukKAyAA)

How can I verify that my value is part of an enum ? Why I have this error ?

**EDIT**

After the help of [nicholas-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139527/nicholas-k) and additional research, I found some publications about this problem:

- [`Cannot read properties of undefined` for enum after bundling with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801508/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-for-enum-after-bundling-with-webpack)
- [Angular use enums from typescript npm package, undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212153/angular-use-enums-from-typescript-npm-package-undefined-error)

I tried on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b9xtwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ferrorcode.enum.ts) and it works

But after trying on my library, no way. I get the same error `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'BAD_CREDENTIALS' in undefined`

```
export class HttpFunctionalErrorCodes {
  static ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND = 'ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND'
  static USER_ALREADY_EXISTS = 'USER_ALREADY_EXISTS'
  static BAD_CREDENTIALS = 'BAD_CREDENTIALS'
}
```

OR

```
export const HttpFunctionalErrorCodes = {
  ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND: 'ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND',
  USER_ALREADY_EXISTS: 'USER_ALREADY_EXISTS',
  BAD_CREDENTIALS: 'BAD_CREDENTIALS'
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o2q4q4?file=tsconfig.json).

Comment: Ok so it's not an Angular problem... Maybe because it's a library... It work's with import to

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b9xtwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ferrorcode.enum.ts

Comment: When transcompiled, it gives us export declare enum in a .d.ts file

Comment: I find now those acrticles :
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212153/angular-use-enums-from-typescript-npm-package-undefined-error

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem!

I used this method:

```
export class HttpFunctionalErrorCodes {
  static ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND = 'ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND'
  static USER_ALREADY_EXISTS = 'USER_ALREADY_EXISTS'
  static BAD_CREDENTIALS = 'BAD_CREDENTIALS'
}
```

And I cleared (deleted) the angular cache (under the folder ".angular/cache/13.3
.6/")